# How to make a split test that reduces scripts from Google Tag Manager in a tool like VisualWebOptimizer

Tags: conversions, a-b-testing, tag-manager, split-testing

We have a website, where we use Google Tag Manager, in order to insert a big amount of scripts.

We want to run a split test, where we reduce these scripts by 70%, which should improve load time (even though the scripts from Tag Manager runs async), and hopefully improve the conversion rate.

However, how do we make a split test, where we can change the amount of scripts fired in Tag Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of Google Tag Manager per se, but a split test is generally an equivalent to a hidden 301. So behind the scene, when someone goes to your page, say `http://www.example.com/GTMPage/`, then the server decides to show data A or data B.

A would be your existing page.

B would be a *refined* version of the page. In effect, in this case you send the client a completely different page even though the user went to the exact same URI.

One potential problem is a client coming back and then seeing *the other page*. However, from what you are saying it would not really look that much different. So that may not be a concern in your situation.

To distinguish the results in Google Analytics, you have to put a parameter in the analytics script. You'll have to check your Analytics account for details on how to do that. More or less it shows as a query string on the URI of the Analytics and in your account you have to "explain" to Analytics what that means.